# How to use function like 'rtrim' in drupal?

Tags: files

I need to remove extension from string, i'm wondering what function could do that ?

Some like the `rtrim($string,'string to remove')`

$string could be the filename

I've added a file into database, now to retrieve it, i want to remove the extension '.epub'

this is the postman response :

```
{
 "code": "0",
 "response": [
{
  "epub": "http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/moby-dick.epub",
  "f_id": "5",
  "uid": "64"
   }
 ]
 }
```

I want to retrieve :

```
"epub": "http://localhost/drupal/sites/default/files/moby-dick",<== no .epub
```

This is my first try :

```
$file = file_load($fid);
            //$realURI = drupal_realpath($file->uri); ca marche


            $realURI = file_create_url($file->uri);
            $new = drupal_basename($realURI, '.epub');
            $n = file_create_url($new);
            $res->epub = $realURI;<== show the new (without .epub)
```

but now it shows :

```
"epub": "http://localhost/drupal/moby-dick"
```

I need to keep `/sites/default/files/` because the file is there 
What can i add for keep it work with the right path please

Thank you

Comment: Just like any other question? See Help Center - if you have problem with code you wrote, post a sample of said code and explain what exactly you tried to do, and how it fails.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Use the Drupal file API to do this; [`file_move()`](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/includes%21file.inc/function/file_move/7) will take care of renaming.

```
  $file = file_load($fid);
  $new_file_uri = preg_replace('/\\.([a-zA-Z]+)$/', '', $file->uri); //Remove .whatever from the file name
  file_move($file, $new_file_uri);
```

Comment: Shawn `Thank you it works, and sorry for being late to test it.  thank you very much